# HashMap key does not live long enough

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to use a `HashMap<String, &Trait>` but I have an error message I don't understand. Here's the code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e32245dbee9b3c209fe473bc1741316a)):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Trait {}

struct Struct;

impl Trait for Struct {}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, &Trait> = HashMap::new();
    let s = Struct;
    map.insert("key".to_string(), &s);
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:36
   |
12 |     map.insert("key".to_string(), &s);
   |                                    ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
13 | }
   | - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

What's happening here? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was solved with [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423), and should not be a concern from Rust 2018 onwards. The answer below is relevant for people using older versions of Rust.

---

`map` outlives `s`, so at some point in `map`'s life (just before destruction), `s` will be invalid. This is solvable by switching their order of construction, and thus of destruction:

```
let s = Struct;
let mut map: HashMap<String, &Trait> = HashMap::new();
map.insert("key".to_string(), &s);
```

If you instead want the `HashMap` to own the references, use owned pointers:

```
let mut map: HashMap<String, Box<Trait>> = HashMap::new();
let s = Struct;
map.insert("key".to_string(), Box::new(s));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But can you please explain why `map` outlives `s`? I thought that variables are destructed at the end of scope, so is there any specific order of destruction?

Comment: "is there any specific order of destruction" → The opposite to the order of construction, because if you have `let x = 1; let y = T(&x);`, the destructor of `y` might need to access `x`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think this is because those vars are allocated in stack.